# How to re-create a mainstoryboard if needed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am creating a notecards app and I need to be able to make a new notecard as many times as I want.  I want to do this so the user is not limited to an amount of note cards.  I need to know how I would create a new view controller (or note card) if they want.  So they creating page can be the same but the new note card cant be the same view as the last note card otherwise it wont be the new one they created.  To get to the point I am trying to create a new view for a new notecard that was created.

Comment: U dont recreate mainstoryboard....what u wanted to do is create a reuseable uiview so that u can use it multiple times with different note page...

Answer (score 2):

Think of a scene in a storyboard as a template. When you invoke a view controller from a storyboard, you get a new copy.

So say your app has a master view controller with a "create note card" button on it. You could connect that button to an IBAction that instantiates and displays a new copy of your note card view controller. The IBAction method might look like this:

```
@IBAction func createNoteCard(UIButton sender)
{
  //Create a new instance of a Note card view controller
  let newCard = 
    self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NoteCard")

  //Put your code to configure the view controller here.

  //Display the new note card view controller to the screen
  self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thabks for the quick response I'll give it a try when I get a chance!

Comment: How would I get to the new view with out the old note card content being on it.  Like make  a copy and then use it when the button is pressed. @Duncan C

Comment: The call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier creates an additional new, empty copy of your view controller. it doesn't give you back an existing one. If you call it twice you get 2 blank view controllers.

Comment: So now how would I confugure the view I want a textview and blue background@DuncanC

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to have one design used multiple times. I think it's more logical to create one `viewController`, and pass it data based on which notecard is selected, or a blank dataset when a new card is "created". This is a common design for use with a UITableView (listing your notecards), which when clicked on, opens the particular card selected. The detail (notecard) view is always the same view, but you pass it different data.