# Getting missing for parameter "Completion" in call

Tags: ios, swift

So I posted a question the other day and the code the person gave to comes with an error I have been unable to solve.  He wont give me a response. So I though that I would just make a new question.

Here is the link to the previous question: [How to re-create a mainstoryboard if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302838/how-to-re-create-a-mainstoryboard-if-needed/34303097?noredirect=1#comment56488953_34303097)

Here is the code that is giving me the problem.

```
@IBAction func Create(sender: AnyObject) {     
    //Create a new instance of a Note card view controller
    let newCard = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NoteCard")        
    self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true)       
}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true)
```

Here is a bit of background on what I am trying to do.  I am trying to make a notecard app.  When the user presses create on a new card it is supposed to create a new view with the new content.

Thanks and contact me with any questions!

Comment: What exactly is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: He fixed my error but now the button does nothing.

Comment: Nm figured out my problem

Comment: As Matt resolved your problem, you might want to consider marking his answer as correct.

Comment: I was going to I just couldnt for 14 mins @TwoStraws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true)
```

to

```
self.presentViewController(newCard, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

This may not solve all your problems, but at least you'll be calling a method that actually exists, unlike what you're doing now.

Comment: Nothing happens when I press the button can I put the hole view in to so that you can take a look @matt

Comment: I was going to I just couldnt do it for 14 mins for some reason

Comment: "Nothing happens when I press the button" Please don't try to change one question into another. That is called "leeching" on Stack Overflow. I answered _the question you asked_. I did tell you that you'd have other problems still. But if you can't solve those yourself, ask a _new question_ — don't try to leech thru the comments.